# Running custom scripts with keyboard shortcuts broken since 17.10 update

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad, 17.10

I have updated from 17.04 to 17.10 and I am still using the Unity DE. I have a custom keyboard shortcut which runs a script to toggle my touchpad on and off (I have a Thinkpad so I usually use the trackpoint).

Before updating, the keyboard shortcut very briefly opened a terminal window, executed the script and then closed. Since the update, the keyboard shortcut does not do anything.

I have tried setting the custom shortcut to:

```
gnome-terminal -e "path/to/script.sh"
```

and

```
path/to/script.sh
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your script using the `xinput` command to turn off the touchpad?  Have you tried running the script while using xorg instead of wayland?

Comment: Yes it is using `xinput`, and I'm using Xorg as far as I know (Xorg is listed in `top`)

Comment: Please include the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Comment: The output was `x11`

Comment: The next step would be to verify that the script is setting properties for the xinput device - can you add the outputs of `xinput` and `cat path/to/script.sh`?

Comment: The script definitely works, I can run it from a terminal and it works as intended. After some fiddling, I've found I can't actually map any new keyboard shortcuts: I tried to set `super + shift + s` to open the settings but it just opens the workspace viewer (as if I had only pressed `super + s`).

Comment: It sounds then like the problem is more with the shortcut keys - I don't user many myself.  Have you tried resetting them all, and redefining the ones that you want?  I would assume that the second for of your shortcut, which does not invoke `gnome-terminal`, would work.